# Regex find duplicate file names from tree output

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext

Please assist in finding duplicate file names from tree output. I'm having trouble finding duplicate file names using regex in SublimeText. The file I am searching is from the output of a `tree` command sent to a text file:

```
src/test/resources
|-- WPCDPS
|   `-- RiskIndicatorsEvaluationRuleTest.feature
|-- Accelerated.feature
|-- AcceptedAFS.feature
|-- AgeValidationRemoval.feature
|-- Anxiety.feature
|-- CheckDisabledOccupation.feature
|-- Extended.feature
|-- Financal.feature
|-- Fainancial.feature
|-- FloridaSpecific.feature
|-- Hypertension.feature
|-- LifeForceOrPending.feature
|-- LifestyleInformation.feature
|-- MinValue.feature
|-- Occupations
|   |-- OccupationTranslation.feature
|   |-- OccupationsWithPreConditions.feature
|   |-- Accelerated.feature
|   `-- OccupationsWithoutPreConditions.feature
|-- Florida.feature
```

I've tried to use different combinations of `(?m)(\bAccelerated\.feature\b)(?=[\s\|\-\n]*\1)` without success.

Comment: how are you getting this `tree` are you using linux tree command

Comment: [`((?!feature)\b\w+\b)(?=[\s\S]*\b(\1)\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/fjvqMP/1) or [`((?<= )[\w.]+$)(?=[\s\S]*(?<= )(\1)$)`](https://regex101.com/r/fjvqMP/2)?

Comment: @ctwheels `((?<= )[\w.]+$)(?=[\s\S]*(?<= )(\1)$)` Amazing it find duplicates! Can you explain how it works? or where I can read more about that, please

Comment: @RaulCabreraAguilar ya but you’ll have to give me a couple of hours, I’m just on the road now. I’ll post it as an answer when I get a chance. You can actually open the link and hover the tokens in regex101, it does pretty well at explaining. There’s also a description section on the right.

Comment: ...or just google for "lookahead lookbehind assertions"

Comment: @user1767754 I used the linux `tree` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/fjvqMP/4)

```
((?<= )[\w.]+$)(?=[\s\S]*(?<= )(\1)$)
```

With the `s` modifier on (single line) as seen in the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/fjvqMP/3)

```
((?<= )[\w.]+$)(?=.*(?<= )(\1)$)
```

**Note**: For some reason the pattern above (with single line mode enabled) results in a timeout on regex101. I've tested the code under **Code Generator** and it works just fine ([doesn't timeout when used in code](https://ideone.com/SYQqKu)).

---

### Explanation

- `((?<= )[\w.]+$)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `(?<= )` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a space
  - `[\w.]+` Match any word character or the dot character one or more times
  - `$` Assert position at the end of the line
- `(?=[\s\S]*(?<= )(\1)$)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

  - `[\s\S]*` Any character any number of times. (We don't use the dot here because it won't match newline characters. You can actually replace `[\s\S]` with `.` if you turn on the single line flag, which forces `.` to also match newlines)
  - `(?<= )` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a space
  - `(\1)` Capture the following into capture group 2

    - `\1` Matches the same text as most recently matched by capture group 1
  - `$` Assert position at the end of the line

In layman's terms, it's matching the entire file name if it's after a space and before the end of the line. Then it's looking ahead to find a duplicate with the same rules (space before, end of line after).